# Remembering URL until authentication is complete

Tags: php, url, url-routing

How do I remember a url in php to serve it to a user after authentication. The idea is the user will request the url but while unauthenticated. In this case, I forward him to the login page, but what's the best practice to save that url so I can serve it to him once authenticated. I thought about saving it in session variables, but not sure about the implementation. Are there best practices for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user goes to `ProtectedPage.php` without being authenticated, this should automatically redirect them to `LoginView.php` (with the previous page's URL attached). They can then proceed to login and the `LoginAction.php` page will redirect them back to the `ProtectedPage.php`

### ProtectedPage.php

```
<?php
    if (!$authenticated) {
        header("Location: /LoginView.php?r=ProtectedPage.php");
    }
?>
```

### LoginView.php

```
<form action="LoginAction.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="r" value="<?php echo $_GET['r'] ?>" />
...
</form>
```

### LoginAction.php

```
<?php
    ... Authenticate the user ...

    if (!empty($_POST['r'])) { header("Location: {$_POST['r']}"); }
    else { header("Location: /"); }
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Put it in a hidden field in the form or save it to a session variable.

Example

login.php?l=account.php (where `l` is the page to go after login).

```
<form action="action/login.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['l'] ? $_GET['l'] : 'index.php'; ?>" name="redirect" />
...
</form>
```

action/login.php

```
<?php

  ... do some checking here...

  if($loggedin){

    redirect($_POST['redirect']);
    // redirect() a wrapper function for header("Location: $url");

  }else{

    redirect('login.php?l='.$_POST['redirect']);
    // go back to login page

  }

?>
```

Comment: Preferably the former. Sessions will cause troubles (redirect to the wrong URL) if the user opens multiple login forms from different locations.

Comment: And of course *NEVER* output raw user input into your HTML. :) use `htmlspecialchars()` on it.

Comment: The only issue here is that most people like to automatically redirect to the login page

Comment: @Lukas - Great point. Twitter uses a session, and it's a usability nightmare if I open a bunch of links in tabs that all require login - I lose all but the last one.